# "Open PowerShell window here" gives "Application not found" error although `powershell.exe` should be find-able in `PATH`

Tags: windows, windows-10, powershell, windows-explorer, context-menu

Windows 10 22H2 19045.3086

With Shift + Right-click, I get a "Open PowerShell window here" entry in the context menu. I think I didn't manually add this entry, it's either enabled by some checkbox or came with windows by default.

Today it stopped working. When I click it, I get this error:

> Application not found

[image: Screenshot of the error message]

The registry entries `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Powershell\command` and `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Powershell\command` do not contain a full path, they are both set to

```
powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location -literalPath '%V'
```

I can not modify them to contain a full path, `regedit` (running as administrator) gives the error `Cannot edit :  Error writing the value's new contents` if I attempt to change them.

From a Command Prompt, while in any folder, I can just start `powershell` and it loads up fine. `echo %PATH%` also shows that `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\` is part of my path. Using Process Explorer, I can also see that it is in the `PATH` variable in the `explorer.exe`'s environment.

Why does this error occur, how can I fix it?

Edit: `sfc /scannow` didn't fix it, rebooting didn't fix it, Windows updates are "up to date".

Edit 2: I ran Process Monitor while clicking on "Open PowerShell window here", and filtered the events to those that were not successful and contained "powershell". I don't know which of these should fail and which shouldn't, though.

```
"FASTIO_NETWORK_QUERY_OPEN","C:\Windows\System32\powershell.exe","FAST IO DISALLOWED","","File System",""
"FASTIO_NETWORK_QUERY_OPEN","C:\Windows\powershell.exe","FAST IO DISALLOWED","","File System",""
"IRP_MJ_CREATE","C:\Windows\System32\powershell.exe","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a","File System",""
"IRP_MJ_CREATE","C:\Windows\powershell.exe","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read Attributes, Disposition: Open, Options: Open Reparse Point, Attributes: n/a, ShareMode: Read, Write, Delete, AllocationSize: n/a","File System",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCR\.cdxml\Microsoft.PowerShellCmdletDefinitionXML.1","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCR\.ps1\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCR\.ps1xml\Microsoft.PowerShellXMLData.1","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCR\.psc1\Microsoft.PowerShellConsole.1","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCR\.psd1\Microsoft.PowerShellData.1","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCR\.psm1\Microsoft.PowerShellModule.1","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCR\.pssc\Microsoft.PowerShellSessionConfiguration.1","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\DropTarget","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Query Value","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCR\Microsoft.PowerShellCmdletDefinitionXML.1\CLSID","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Query Value","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCR\Microsoft.PowerShellConsole.1\CLSID","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Query Value","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCR\Microsoft.PowerShellData.1\CLSID","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Query Value","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCR\Microsoft.PowerShellModule.1\CLSID","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Query Value","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCR\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\CLSID","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Query Value","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCR\Microsoft.PowerShellSessionConfiguration.1\CLSID","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Query Value","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCR\Microsoft.PowerShellXMLData.1\CLSID","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Query Value","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\.cdxml\Microsoft.PowerShellCmdletDefinitionXML.1","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\.ps1\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\.ps1xml\Microsoft.PowerShellXMLData.1","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\.psc1\Microsoft.PowerShellConsole.1","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\.psd1\Microsoft.PowerShellData.1","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\.psm1\Microsoft.PowerShellModule.1","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\.pssc\Microsoft.PowerShellSessionConfiguration.1","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\Directory\Background\shell\Powershell","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\Directory\background\shell\Powershell","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Maximum Allowed","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\Directory\background\shell\Powershell","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Query Value, Enumerate Sub Keys","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\Directory\background\shell\Powershell","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\DropTarget","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Query Value","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\command","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Maximum Allowed","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\command","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Query Value","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\Microsoft.PowerShellCmdletDefinitionXML.1\CLSID","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Query Value","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\Microsoft.PowerShellConsole.1\CLSID","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Query Value","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\Microsoft.PowerShellData.1\CLSID","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Query Value","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\Microsoft.PowerShellModule.1\CLSID","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Query Value","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\CLSID","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Query Value","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\Microsoft.PowerShellSessionConfiguration.1\CLSID","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Query Value","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Classes\Microsoft.PowerShellXMLData.1\CLSID","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Query Value","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\powershell.exe","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppModel\Lookaside\machine\SOFTWARE\Classes\.cdxml\Microsoft.PowerShellCmdletDefinitionXML.1","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppModel\Lookaside\machine\SOFTWARE\Classes\.ps1\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppModel\Lookaside\machine\SOFTWARE\Classes\.ps1xml\Microsoft.PowerShellXMLData.1","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppModel\Lookaside\machine\SOFTWARE\Classes\.psc1\Microsoft.PowerShellConsole.1","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppModel\Lookaside\machine\SOFTWARE\Classes\.psd1\Microsoft.PowerShellData.1","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppModel\Lookaside\machine\SOFTWARE\Classes\.psm1\Microsoft.PowerShellModule.1","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppModel\Lookaside\machine\SOFTWARE\Classes\.pssc\Microsoft.PowerShellSessionConfiguration.1","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppModel\Lookaside\machine\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\DropTarget","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppModel\Lookaside\machine\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\powershell.exe","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppModel\Lookaside\user\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\powershell.exe","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppModel\Lookaside\user\software\Classes\Microsoft.PowerShellCmdletDefinitionXML.1\CLSID","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppModel\Lookaside\user\software\Classes\Microsoft.PowerShellConsole.1\CLSID","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppModel\Lookaside\user\software\Classes\Microsoft.PowerShellData.1\CLSID","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppModel\Lookaside\user\software\Classes\Microsoft.PowerShellModule.1\CLSID","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppModel\Lookaside\user\software\Classes\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\CLSID","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppModel\Lookaside\user\software\Classes\Microsoft.PowerShellSessionConfiguration.1\CLSID","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\AppModel\Lookaside\user\software\Classes\Microsoft.PowerShellXMLData.1\CLSID","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read","Registry",""
"RegOpenKey","HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\powershell.exe","NAME NOT FOUND","Desired Access: Read","Registry",""
"RegQueryKey","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell","BUFFER TOO SMALL","Query: Name, Length: 0","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\ActivationModel","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 32","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\AppliesTo","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 144","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\CheckSupportedTypes","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 12","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\CommandFlags","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 16","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\CommandStateHandler","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 90","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\CurrentFolderAsSelection","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 12","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\DownloadInvokeDisabled","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 12","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\ExplorerCommandHandler","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 12","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\ExplorerCommandHandler","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 90","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\ExtendedSubCommandsKey","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 144","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\FolderHandler","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 90","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\FriendlyAppName","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 144","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\HasLUAShield","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 144","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\HideBasedOnVelocityID","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 16","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\Icon","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 144","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\ImpliedSelectionModel","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 12","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\ImpliedSelectionModel","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 16","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\InvokeCommandOnSelection","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 16","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\IsInContextMenu","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 12","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\LegacyDisable","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 90","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\MUIVerb","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 144","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\MaxDownloadFileSize","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 16","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\MultiSelectModel","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 60","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\NoSmartScreen","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 12","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\OnlyInBrowserWindow","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 12","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\OnlyInTabWindow","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 12","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\OpenControlPanel","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 144","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\OpenControlPanelPage","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 144","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\PaneVisibleProperty","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 144","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\Position","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 140","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\ProgrammaticAccessOnly","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 12","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\ReadWriteRequired","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 12","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\SendToVerb","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 144","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\SeparatorAfter","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 12","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\SeparatorBefore","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 12","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\StaticVerbOnly","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 12","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\SubCommands","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 12","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\SuppressionPolicy","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 16","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\SuppressionPolicyEx","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 144","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\SuppressionPolicyEx","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 90","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\command\DelegateExecute","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 12","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\command\DelegateExecute","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 144","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\command\DelegateExecute","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 90","Registry","Read"
"RegQueryValue","HKCR\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\command\command","NAME NOT FOUND","Length: 144","Registry","Read"
```

#### Temporary Workaround

Seeing that `explorer.exe` attempts to load `C:\Windows\powershell.exe`, creating a symlink under this path works as a temporary work around, i.e.:

```
mklink C:\Windows\powershell.exe C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

makes the context-menu entry work again. I don't think the link is supposed to be there, though, so I'm still looking for a proper solution.

Comment: What version of powershell is this? If it's version 7, have you tried to repaired, uninstalled/reinstalled?

Comment: The PowerShell I can launch comes from `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`, so v1.0? `PSVersion` is 5.1.19041.3031 inside that. I don't think I installed anything manually, it's simply the PowerShell that came with Windows 10. Searching for "powershell" doesn't give any results in "Add or remove programs". "Windows PowerShell 2.0" was checked in "Turn Windows features on or off", I turned it off and rebooted, but it didn't remove the PS version that I can start, so I think it's something different.

Comment: In the registry `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\MuiCache\206\417C44EB`, do you have the following string value: `@"C:\Windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe ",-108`?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio: I don't have it either, but it works for me.

Comment: @harrymc Same result for `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\MuiCache\206\417C44EB`?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio: Not either.

Comment: @harrymc I have checked on a different machine and the pattern seems to be `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Local Settings\MuiCache\` followed by a number, followed by alphanumeric characters. The key contains a string  `@"C:\Windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe ",-108` whose value is `Run with Powershell`. Can you check on your side?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio: I have a similar key, but not an entry for "Run with Powershell". I only have "Document Encryption" and "Windows PowerShell ISE" entries.

Comment: Did you end up fixing it?

Comment: @idn I did what I wrote under "Temporary Workaround" in the question, that made the context menu entry work again for me. I didn't find out why it stopped working though.

Answer (score 1):

I also have this problem. Explorer can't open powershell.exe and most likely searches for it in the C:\Windows directory. But I solved the error by changing the registry parameter value in the directory: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\Powershell\command`. I changed it to `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location -literalPath '%V'` and it works well.

If you can't change the registry parameter, you need to open the permissions of the Powershell folder by clicking on it in the context menu, then click on the "Advanced" button, and change the owner by clicking on the blue "Change" button. After that, you need to put down in the bottom field your user name, then click on the "Check Names" button and press "OK". Further, you need to check the boxes "Replace owner on subcontainers and objects" and "Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission" and press "OK". In the pop-up window, also press "OK", and in the first window of permissions, you need to choose Administrators and give them full control. You have access to all of these parameters. If you want to change back the owner, you need to do all these points, but in the bottom field of owner, you need to put `NT SERVICE\TrustedInstaller` instead of your user name. You can watch a tutorial with images just by googling it, or watch this article, for example: https://www.groovypost.com/howto/take-full-permissions-control-edit-protected-registry-keys/

Comment: Its tok confusing, can you improve it.

Comment: What do you not like? If my first language is not English or I couldn't answer as you wanted, is that reason to shit me after the first post? What's wrong with this stackowerflow and this service? I have been given only negative comments and nothing of gratitude.

Comment: I did what you said and didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I searched and listed below all the registry context-menu entries
that contain `@shell32.dll,-8508`, which is the text for
"Open PowerShell window here".

Check if yours are the same. You may also save the this text in a `.reg`
file and double-click it to import into the registry.
I suggest before doing registry updates to take precautions and at least
create a System Restore save-point, to be able to rollback to the
current state in an emergency.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Drive\shell\Powershell]
@="@shell32.dll,-8508"
"Extended"=""
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""
"ShowBasedOnVelocityId"=dword:00639bc8

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Drive\shell\Powershell\command]
@="powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location -literalPath '%V'"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\Powershell]
@="@shell32.dll,-8508"
"Extended"=""
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""
"ShowBasedOnVelocityId"=dword:00639bc8

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\shell\Powershell\command]
@="powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location -literalPath '%V'"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\background\shell\Powershell]
@="@shell32.dll,-8508"
"Extended"=""
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""
"ShowBasedOnVelocityId"=dword:00639bc8

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Directory\background\shell\Powershell\command]
@="powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location -literalPath '%V'"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\Powershell]
@="@shell32.dll,-8508"
"Extended"=""
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""
"ShowBasedOnVelocityId"=dword:00639bc8

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\Powershell\command]
@="powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location -literalPath '%V'"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Powershell]
@="@shell32.dll,-8508"
"Extended"=""
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""
"ShowBasedOnVelocityId"=dword:00639bc8

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\Powershell\command]
@="powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location -literalPath '%V'"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Powershell]
@="@shell32.dll,-8508"
"Extended"=""
"NoWorkingDirectory"=""
"ShowBasedOnVelocityId"=dword:00639bc8

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\Powershell\command]
@="powershell.exe -noexit -command Set-Location -literalPath '%V'"
```

Comment: Thanks! Sadly, I checked all these, and they're all set on my machine.

Comment: Use [regscanner](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/regscanner.html) to fast-search the entire registry for `C:\Windows\powershell.exe`, to find out where it comes from. Because I don't have any such thing.

Comment: There are 8 MuiCache entries caching the `ApplicationName` and `FriendlyAppName` of the symlink I've created (internet says: [is](https://windowsir.blogspot.com/2005/12/mystery-of-muicachesolved.html) [expected](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/muicache_view.html). No other results. I think `explorer.exe` is simply looking in `C:\Windows` and `C:\Windows\System32` because these are default search paths. The main question remains though: Why does `explorer` not search in all paths specified in `PATH`, where it should be able to find `powershell.exe` without any problem?

Comment: I don't have `powershell.exe` inside `C:\Windows`, but  "Open PowerShell window here" works quite well. It's likely caused by some registry problem on your computer. If all your settings are the same as in my above answer, you will need to find where it comes from. Are you sure your registry is identical to my answer?